# design a set to classes to report battery/power status of different alexa devices

Tags: oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, object-oriented-analysis

I was asked below quesion in Amazon sde2 low level design interview recently and I have shown below my solution during the interview. I was rejected in this round. Can you help me with a solution of this problem in any object oriented language?

```
// There are a wide variety of Alexa devices
// 1. Alexa devices that only have a speaker (Echo Dot, Echo Flex, https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FZ8S74R)
// 2. Alexa devices that only have a screen/display (Alexa enabled Microwave or AC, https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07894S727)
// 3. Alexa devices that have both, speaker and screen (Echo Show, Echo Spot, https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08KJN3333).
// 4. Alexa devices that have neither a speaker, nor a screen (Echo Input, Echo link, https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0798DVZCY).
// 5. Alexa devices that have a speaker, but can be connected to a display (FireTV cube, https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08XMDNVX6).
// 
// Also,
// 1. Some Alexa devices that have batteries (Fire Tablets, Echo Tap, Echo Buds, https://www.amazon.com/dp/B085WTYQ4X)
// 2. Others that do not have batteries (Echo Dot, Echo Show).
//
// Design a set of classes that will report the current battery/power status to the user.
// Depending on the hardware, the response may need to be spoken, or displayed on a screen, or both.
// Also, depending on whether there is a battery or not, the status message will differ.
// For example, if the device is a Tablet which has a battery, a speaker, and a display, and currently
// it happens to be plugged in and recharging (let's say at 75%), then your code should return the following:
//      {
//          "say": "Current battery level is 75% and charging",
//          "display": "Current battery level is 75% and charging"
//      }
//
// Whereas if the device is an Echo Dot, which has a speaker but no battery and no screen,
// then your code should only return:
//      {
//          "say": "Currently plugged into wall power"
//      }
//
// and should NOT attempt to display anything (since there is no screen).
//
// For simplicity, ignore the details of speech generation and image/visual card generation, we can safely assume those are provided.
// Focus more on modeling the Alexa devices and their properties, and returning the correct responses.
```

my solution is below in c++

```
class Battery
{
    int percentage;
    public:
    string getStatus()
    {
        string msg = to_string(percentage);
        return msg;
    }
};

class Power
{
    bool isCharging;
    public:
    string getStatus()
    {
        string msg = isCharging ? "" : "";
        return msg;
    }
};

enum OutputType { DISPLAY , SPEAKER };
class Output
{
    OutputType outputType;
    public:
    void print(string msg) = 0;
};
```

and:

```
class Speaker : public Output
{
  public:
  void print(string msg)
  {
    ...    
  }
};

class Display : public Output
{
  public:
  void print(string msg)
  {
   ...   
  }
};

class Device {
    public:
    virtual void printStatus() = 0;
};
```

and

```
class EchoDot : public Device
{
  Output* speaker;
  Power *power;
  public:
  void printStatus()
  {
     string msg = power->getStatus();
    speaker->print(msg);
  }
};

class EchoShow : public Device
{
  Output* speaker;
  Output* display;
  Power *power;
  public:
  void printStatus()
  {
    string msg = power->getStatus();
    speaker->print(msg);
    display->print(msg);
  }
};
```

and:

```
class FireTV : public Device
{
  list<Output*> outputs;
  Power *power;
  public:
  void printStatus()
  {
    string msg = power->getStatus();
    foreach output in outputs
        output->print(msg);
  }
  void addOutput(Output* output)
  {
      outputs.push_front(output);
  }
  void removeOutput(Output* output)
  {
      
  }
};
```

He told me to make the design extensible so that tomorrow if a new device comes up with an array of led displays , it can be added easily with minimal changes to existing code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

My code is in C# and I would define such architecture:

```
    public interface ISpeaker
    {
        public void SpeakMessage(string message);
    }

    public interface IDisplay
    {
        public void ShowMessage(string message);
    }

    public interface IPlugDisplay : IDisplay
    {
        bool IsConnected { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IPowerSource
    {
        bool IsPluggedIn { get; protected set; }
    }
    public interface IOutlet : IPowerSource
    {
    }

    public interface IBattery : IPowerSource
    {
        int PowerPercentage { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class ADevice
    {
    }

    public class DeviceEcho : ADevice, ISpeaker, IOutlet
    {
        private bool _connected = true;//In order to work it must be plugged in
        public DeviceEcho() { }

        public bool IsPluggedIn { get { return _connected; } set { } }

        public void SpeakMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Say - " + message);
        }
    }

    public class DeviceAC : ADevice, IDisplay, IOutlet
    {
        private bool _connected = true;//In order to work it must be plugged in
        public DeviceAC()
        {
        }
        public bool IsPluggedIn { get { return _connected; } set { } }

        public void ShowMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Display - " + message);
        }
    }

    public class DeviceFireTablet : ADevice, ISpeaker, IDisplay, IBattery
    {
        public DeviceFireTablet(int powerPercentage, bool isPluggedIn)
        {
            this.PowerPercentage = powerPercentage;
            this.IsPluggedIn = isPluggedIn;
        }

        public int PowerPercentage { get; set; }

        public bool IsPluggedIn { get; set; }

        public void ShowMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Display - " + message);
        }

        public void SpeakMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Say - " + message);
        }
    }
    public class DeviceLink : ADevice, IOutlet
    {
        private bool _connected = true;//In order to work it must be plugged in
        public DeviceLink()
        {
        }
        public bool IsPluggedIn { get { return _connected; } set { } }
    }


    public class UseDevice
    {

        private ADevice m_device;
        public UseDevice(ADevice device)
        {
            m_device = device;
        }
        public void ShowStatus()
        {
            string messageBuilder = "Currently plugged into wall power";
            if (m_device is IBattery)
                messageBuilder = ((IPowerSource)m_device).IsPluggedIn ? $"Current battery level is {((IBattery)m_device).PowerPercentage}% and charging" :
                    $"Current battery level is {((IBattery)m_device).PowerPercentage}%  and discharging";
            if (m_device is ISpeaker)
                ((ISpeaker)m_device).SpeakMessage(messageBuilder);


            if (m_device is IPlugDisplay && ((IPlugDisplay)m_device).IsConnected)
                ((IPlugDisplay)m_device).ShowMessage(messageBuilder);
            else
                if (m_device is IDisplay)
                ((IDisplay)m_device).ShowMessage(messageBuilder);
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-- DeviceEcho --");
            new UseDevice(new DeviceEcho()).ShowStatus();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("-- DeviceAC --");
            new UseDevice(new DeviceAC()).ShowStatus();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("-- DeviceFireTablet on batteries --");
            new UseDevice(new DeviceFireTablet(75, false)).ShowStatus();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("-- DeviceFireTablet plugged in --");
            new UseDevice(new DeviceFireTablet(75, true)).ShowStatus();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("-- DeviceLink - no message --");
            new UseDevice(new DeviceLink()).ShowStatus();
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answering my question. I have two follow up questions

1. It is mentioned in the question that FireTV can be connected to a Display dynamically. You have not written code for this part.

2. you have not written code for EchoShow.  Also interviewer told me that EchoShow and EchoDot has lot of common and that should be put in a common base class.

3. I think Speaker, Display, battery, Power are "have" properties of a device not "is" property so instead of using inheritance should not you use composition?

Comment: Yes, u can add yourself FireTV by addding the wanted interfaces in this case IPlugDisplay  (the logic is already functional in ShowStatus) and you can have a constructor where u set IsConnected for it. Also define a class for EchoShow and follow the same ideea. I didn't implement all... I just gave u the direction...

Comment: 1. why you did not use composition rather used inheritance?
2. why you have not defined _connected attribute in DeviceFireShow rather defined IsPluggedIn attribute
3. you have defined _connected attribute in DeviceEcho DeviceAC DeviceLink. should not you put this attribbute in a common base class?

Comment: Because I use SOLID principles where u have interface segregation.